# Logrotating all logs in a directory causes date duplication

Tags: linux, logging, logrotate

I have a logrotate config that looks like this:

```
/var/log/update-job/*.log {
    daily
    rotate 7
    compress
    delaycompress
    size 0k
    missingok
    copytruncate
    notifempty
    dateext
    dateformat %Y%m%d.
    extension log
    su root syslog
}
```

In theory, what I'd like this to do is, upon meeting a logfile named `thelog.log`, to rotate it to `thelog.20150622.log`, and the next day to `thelog.20150623.log` and so on. I want this for multiple logfiles with arbitrary filenames, for example, there might be `thelog.log` and `anotherlog.log` inside the folder at the same time.

What I *actually see* is, though:

```
thelog.20150622.20150623.log
thelog.20150623.log
thelog.log
anotherlog.20150622.20150623.log
anotherlog.20150623.log
anotherlog.log
```

The reason is that the glob pattern (`/var/log/update-job/*.log`) matches the rotated files too. I thought logrotate was clever enough to use the dateformat directive to figure out that a file is rotated, but apparently this isn't the case.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

A workaround might be to remove `delaycompress`, so that files get compressed to .log.gz upon rotation, so that they are no longer matched by the glob pattern. I'd like to find a less hacky solution, though.

Comment: The problem is in your config - files that are being matched. Take a look here and you will find the same problem already solved: https://serverfault.com/questions/76541/logrotate-creates-long-names-and-does-not-delete-logs

Comment: So, essentially, the answer is that no, there's nothing to be done, I need to match differently or change the way I use dateext, right? Thanks.

Comment: You should just modify the match string pattern. Yours is to extensive. Try to use `?` to match single character or narrow the matching to letters only with `[a-z]` char classes: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67860/how-does-logrotate-treat-globbing

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that - the problem is that the log names often include numbers as well, so it's not that easy to distinguish them with regexes. But I'll try. You should make your comment an answe, so I can choose it.